# Content Server - Como añadir un objeto 'Classification' a un documento desde la REST API

Tags: rest

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion JAVA de carga de documentos sobre Content Server 16.2 de OpenText usando la REST API.

Necesito añadir/vincular un objeto 'Classification' ya definido a un documento (node) mediante la API REST pero no encuentro información al respecto.

Por ejemplo:
Esta es mi llamada REST:

```
POST http://<server>/OTCS/cs.exe/api/v2/nodes
```

Y los dos parametros:

- body `{
  "parent_id": "137072",
  "name": "example.tmp",
  "type": "144"
  }`
- file: (a MultipartFile)

Es posible hacerlo mediante esta REST API?

Comment: ¿Es una API de terceros o una API que estás programando tú? Si es lo primero la única solución es encontrar la forma de consultarla para que te devuelva ese dato que requieres. Si es lo segundo, entonces tendrías que abrir un parámetro de consulta que devuelva ese dato.

Comment: Yo estoy siguiendo la siguiente documentacion para desarrollar las peticiones a los servicios REST desplegados por Content Server de OpenText. https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fresources%2Fapis%2Fcs-rest-api-for-cs-16-2%23!%2Fcategories&tab=501